# Add events to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, fullcalendar

I have a JSON string of events:

```
var data = [{"title":"Event","start":"2017-04-23T18:00:00","end":"2017-04-23T18:00:00"},{"title":"Event 2","start":"2017-04-23T11:15:00","end":"2017-04-23T11:15:00"},{"title":"Event 3","start":"2017-04-26T08:32:00","end":"2017-04-26T08:32:00"}]
```

how can i add it into my viewRender?

```
viewRender: function(view, element){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getevents.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                // data is the data JSON string above
            },
            fail: function() {
                alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
            }
           });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

Comment: @mr.void the first piece of code looks about right but it says the data type is in xml. it doesn't say anything about json. it says to use a url if its json but i only have the json string.

Comment: you can use XML or JSON, it doesn't matter. The important thing is that it can be parsed to a JS array in the correct format. If you use JSON, then it's basically automatic. Therefore it's trivial to observer that JSON can be used, because JSON represents JavaScript objects/arrays natively.

Comment: Or you could use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ which is far simpler, if you can make your server-side method compliant (which hopefully wouldn't be difficult). Using viewRender is completely the wrong approach as mr void already mentioned.

Comment: Using your **var data = [{ /* snip ... */ }];** above, using it directly like **$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: data});** seems to work as-is [events as an array](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/)

Comment: @smcd I'd agree except that the OP's sample code using the "viewRender" shows that in reality the intention is clearly to download the events data whenever the date/view is changed. It's only the OP's approach to this and understanding of the fullCalendar architecture which is the problem.